# Unable to remove airplane mode keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, airplane-mode

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and can't figure out a way to remove the keyboard shortcut to airplane.

First I tried to remove the shortcut, but airplane mode doesn't appear in the settings. Then I tried to remap it to a custom shortcut through the default settings, but when I press <kbd>F7</kbd> to enter the key I only toggle airplane mode.

I've also tried to remove the shortcut from `dconf-editor` (`org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys`), but just as in the default settings, the airplane mode shortcut doesn't appear.

Any ideas on how to remap the button?